# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Reload configs files without redeploying the whole app?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to load what is in **.ebextention** without redeploying the whole application with `eb deploy`? It seems restarting Apache is not enough.

exemple of config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_remove_old_cron_jobs:
    command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
  02_cronjobs:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cron_jobs.txt > /etc/cron.d/cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron_job"
    leader_only: true
  03_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The plain answer is no. The config files are only executed upon deployment as part of the EB scripting pipeline. If it's only a one time operation you'd like to perform, simply `eb ssh` the instance and perform these manually. Upon next deploy they'll be done automatically via your config files.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another container_commands e.g.:

```
04_reload_files:
    command: "sudo service httpd reload"
```

Note this will work with Amazon Linux but not Amazon Linux 2 where you would need to do:

```
04_reload_files:
    command: "sudo systemctl reload httpd.service"
```

AWS have a new preferred way of interacting with webserver config during deployment using the following structure (for apache) rather than .ebextensions:

```
~/workspace/my-app/
|-- .ebextensions
|   -- httpd-proxy.config
|-- .platform
|   -- httpd
|      -- conf.d
|         -- port5000.conf
|         -- ssl.conf
-- index.jsp
```

Some more info available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html